# Access USB HID-device from Windows CE

Tags: winapi, usb, windows-ce, hid

within an existing application I'm communicationg with a HID-device using some code similar to the one from https://github.com/obdev/v-usb/blob/master/libs-host/hiddata.c (which makes use of HDEVINFO, SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA and several HidD_*()-functions to send and receive reports).

Now I plan to communicate with the same device using Windows CE 5/6. It seems these functions and structures do not exist there, so the code is not directly compatible/reusable.

So my question: how can I send/receive reports to/from a USB HID-device on WinCE? Does anybody know some examples/documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In CE there is an HID layer that can be used to send/receive HID reports but to access it you'll have to write a driver. You can check the mouse and keyd drivers under WINCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\DRIVER\USB\CLASS\HID\CLIENTS to see how they interface with the HID layer.

Comment: To confirm this: WinCE does not come with a USB HID device driver by default?